# The switch button turns back to on itself when goes to some other tab

Tags: flutter, dart

I have switch button and when I go to some other tab and come again it turns on itself. I want it to stay On or Off depending on what last selected. Though the value are getting saved in data base correctly but when go to some other tab it is back to On. This is code below.

```
  bool _hideProfile = false;

  ListTile(
    title: Card(
         color: themeProvider.isDarkMode? black :white,
         child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right: 20),
                child: SwitchListTile(
                 title: _hideProfile? Text("Profile hidden",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),)
                 :Text(" Profile visible",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                 secondary: _hideProfile?
                 Icon(Icons.visibility_off_outlined,color: lRed ):
                 Icon(Icons.visibility_outlined,color: Colors.green),
                 activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                 inactiveThumbColor: mRed,      
                 inactiveTrackColor: dRed,
                 value: _hideProfile,
                 onChanged:(value){
                 setState(() {
                        _hideProfile = value;
                    });
                 String userStatus = 'active';
                     if (value) {
                           userStatus = 'hidden';
                     }

      CreateAccountData(userStatus: userStatus ,);

      _reference.doc(auth.currentUser.uid).update(
              {
                "userStatus" : userStatus,
               }).then((_){
              print('Profile hidden: $value');
             });
            }
           ),
          ),
          ),
         ),
```

Comment: where you put   bool _hideProfile = false; ?

Comment: its inside  the class where we define all the variables usually.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `setState()` for the state management so when you will go to some other page then the variable will loose it's state means it will get `disposed` and when you will come back it will start what ever you had set as default.

Now to over come this use state management package like `provider`, `mobx`, `bloc` etc.

Comment: do I have to make a separate provider class or it can be done here only?

Comment: @GAGANSINGH yes it is a good practice to separate your business logic from UI